# EF6.1 beta 1 how to get the Tooling Consolidation feature?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I was watching the [Building Modern Web Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/Building-Modern-Web-Apps/05) tutorial, and I want to know how to get the entity data model wizard, which is new in this version of the EF6.1 Beta 1, because I installed the latest EF version from nuget, but that only install the binaries, any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new tooling can be downloaded and installed from here...

[Entity Framework 6.1.0 Beta 1 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41928)

Comment: Right after @anthonychu answered my question, and solved my problem, I was reading my twitter and found this [First look at (beta of) EF 6.1 Designer](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/first-look-at-beta-of-ef-6-1-designer/), and article by **Julie Lerman**

Comment: For the sake of posterity, the official (not beta) link for this can be found at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762